# Lock certain cells depending on value from another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Im looking to lock a particular range of cells based on the input from a drop down in a row of data?

For example, In every row, third cell asks a question - "YES" or "NO" via a dropdown is given.If the user selects "NO", then remaining three cells has to be locked. However, if the user selects, "Yes", then the remainder of the cells shall remain available to enter data into.

```
   A         B          C            D         E         F  
| S.No   |  ID    |  Response   |  TIme  |  Value  | Expense | 
| 1      |  12345 |  NO         |  ----  |  ----   |  ----   |  (Locked Cells)
| 2      |  67y45 |  YES        |  44    |  1.68   |    1500 |  (UnLocked Cells)
| 3      |  12456 |  NO         |  ----  |  ----   |  ----   |  (Locked Cells)
```

like D2 to F2 has to be locked while D3 to F3 should be available for entry and again D4 to F4 is locked and so on,...

I tried the below code but it didn't lock the cells or didn't do any actions as far I observed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("C2:C160") = "YES" Then
        Range("D2:D160").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("C2:C160") = "NO" Then
        Range("D2:D160").Locked = True
        Range("E2:E160").Locked = True
        Range("F2:F160").Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Took **160** as the highest range.

Any help would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: If you select the Range eg `Range("C2:C160") = "yes"` then VBA scans for the data of the entire range, not if any of the cells inside range contain the keyword yes. That's also why your code doesn't work

Comment: @Rawrplus : Oh got it, could you please help me here .. I'm not sure how to move forward, thank you..

Comment: gladly, but Vityata;s code should work and it seems like a good implementation to m, so I don't think it really changes much (other than different implementation method)

Comment: @Rawrplus Vitayata really helped a lot and  but I could not get the code running.. its still allowing values to be entered ..Any alternative would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C160")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Me.Unprotect Password:="password"

    If Target = "YES" Then            
        Target.Offset(0,1).Resize(1,3).Locked = False
    ElseIf Target = "NO" Then
        Target.Offset(0,1).Resize(1,3).Locked = True        
    End If

    Me.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

The idea is to check the `Target` value. It is the cell, which is changed. Thus, you can start with `Intersect()`, which checks whether the changed cell is in `Range("C2:C160")`:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C160")) Then Exit Sub
```

Then try to see whether the changed cells are more than 1:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

At the end, based on the `"YES"` and "NO" you can give lock cells. You may consider using `UCase()`, in order to make your code work for "yes" as well"

```
If UCase(Target) = "YES" Then
...
ElseIf UCase(Target) = "NO" Then
```

---

Concerning locked and unlocked cells and whether you can select them, see this article, the properties are explained quite well:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a

Comment: Really appreciate your input and time here... I tried your code but it said `the cell or chart you are trying to change is protected....` so I unprotected the sheet but now its not locking the cell when NO is selected.. When I ran, the line - `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C160")) Then` is getting highlighted in Yellow on Debug window... I'm very very new to VB/macros so really have no idea whats wrong here

Comment: @Goku - where do you put the code? It should be in a worksheet. And there was something I have forgotten in my answer, edited now. Keep on pressing `F8`, it is a good way to debug.

Comment: Right, I've put it on the worksheet and the corresponding right hand values says `Change` and saved it. When I tried to select NO,still it allows to enter values on the other cells

Comment: @Goku you have to give a password and protect the worksheet as well. The `.Locked` is just a property. Add `Me.Unprotect Password:="password"` and `Me.Protect Password:="password"`. Actually the password is optional.

Comment: I tried the same, I unprotected the sheet 1st then modified the code by adding the 2 lines suggested as below `Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Me.Protect Password:="password"
    Me.Unprotect Password:="password"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C160")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`

still I'm able to add the values if selected NO.. sorry for bothering so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172896/discussion-between-goku-and-vityata).

Comment: I think the problem here is that your code will lock ALL cells in the range `D2:F160` rather than just the offset from the cell that says `Yes` - Maybe try `Target.Offset(0,1).Resize(1,3).Locked` kind-of idea....

Comment: @JohnBustos - makes sense, probably the OP does not want the whole range. I have edited.

Comment: @JohnBustos @Vityata : I want the immediate 3 cells blocked and not all the cells, like if `C7 = NO` , I want D7, E7 and F7 to be blocked and the remaining cells in the sheet should be untouched.. same goes for the other cells having `NO`

Comment: I tried the code but its blocking the entire sheet if I select NO :( Thanks again

Comment: @Goku - strange. Try from complete scratch, it should be working. And try the last edit :)

Comment: @Goku - see the link in the answer. It is based on your Excel settings what the cells are doing once they are locked.